# Run multiple MySQL queries from PHP | Why is this not working?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run multiple queries on some mysql dbs from a php file. However it is not working. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Here is the contents of the php file:

```
<?
require_once('/home/xxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxx/dbconnect.php');
$query = "
TRUNCATE TABLE db2.table1;
INSERT INTO db2.table1
SELECT 
       column1, column2, column3, column4
       FROM db1.table1;

TRUNCATE TABLE db2.table2;
INSERT INTO db2.table2
SELECT 
       column1, column2, column3, column4 
       FROM db1.table2;
ANALYZE TABLE db2.table2;
";

$result = @mysql_query($query);    
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making only one query. Read docs for [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

> mysql_query() sends a unique query
>   (multiple queries are not supported)
>   to the currently active database on
>   the server that's associated with the
>   specified link_identifier.

You should split each query in it's own string and send it one by one to MySQL.

```
$query1 = "TRUNCATE TABLE db2.table1;";
$query2 = "INSERT INTO db2.table1
SELECT 
       column1, column2, column3, column4
       FROM db1.table1;";

$query3 = "TRUNCATE TABLE db2.table2;";
$query4 = "INSERT INTO db2.table2
SELECT 
       column1, column2, column3, column4 
       FROM db1.table2;";
$query5= "ANALYZE TABLE db2.table2;";

$result1 = @mysql_query($query1);  
$result2 = @mysql_query($query2);  
$result3 = @mysql_query($query3);  
$result4 = @mysql_query($query4);  
$result5 = @mysql_query($query5);
```

Or use some other interface function that supports multiple queries. Personally I don't know if there is such a thing.

Comment: If you have mysqli installed, you can execute multiple queries in one function call: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Answer (score 4):

The most important thing to do in such a case is debugging:

- Remove the `@` prefix to see errors
- Add a `echo mysql_error()` if mysql_query() returns `false` to see mySQL's error messages

in your specific case, `mysql_query()` is not able to execute more than one statement. The easiest solution is to use two separate commands.